# Read conf.properties file from web app under Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I put a file with properties to *tomcat_folder*/conf and try to read it:

```
InputStream input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf.properties");
properties.load(input);
```

But in fact I receive 'null'. I tried to print out current folder and it shows "home/username" folder (I wanted to get to the conf folder from current one).

"catalina.properties" contains "shared.loader=", so theoretically this file should be read from there anyway, but it isn't...

Is there any solution on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.
I added ${catalina.home}/conf to catalina.properties -> shared.loader

```
shared.loader=${catalina.home}/conf
```

And

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf.properties");
```

started to open correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the classloader you get when calling this.getClass().getClassloader() is the shared one. Actually it depends on where "this" is.

I'm not sure you will be able to get this file via classloader, even though I think the current classloader should delegate. You can maybe get the shared classloader through some tomcat api.

You could try the CATALINA_HOME/BASE property to get to the file via filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
properties.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().
        getResource("filename.properties").openStream());`
```

Works for me on JBoss 6.

Comment: No, I'm still looking for .properties file in /home/username.